# awk match 1st 3 columns from two files and print remainings from file1

Tags: awk, match, multiple-columns

hi just came with struggle in matching, and tried several matching hints here on forum but i cannot apply any of them as i need to compare just from file2 column $1,$2,$3 from file1 with column $1,$2,$3 and if there is match just print remaining colums from file1 along with columns from file2
any help with awk code description is welcomed

this not worked:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { a[$2] = $0; next } { line = a[$2] FS $1; for(i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) line = line FS $i; print line }' file1 file2
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2,$3]=$0;next}($1,$2,$3)in a{print a[$1,$2,$3]" | "$0}' file1 file2
```

file1 contains

```
A 97276 X700 0 6 DD V8 2006
A 97276 X700 0 6 DD V8 2007
A 97276 X700 0 6 DD V8 2008
A 97276 X700 0 6 DD V8 2009
A 97276 X700 0 6 DD V8 2010
A 97276 X700 0 6 DD V8 2011
A 97276 X700 0 6 DD V8 2012
A 97276 X700 0 6 DD V8 2013
B 3254 A22 0 8 DD BIX 06
B 3254 A22 0 8 DD BIX 07
B 3254 A22 0 8 DD BIX 08
B 3254 A22 0 8 DD BIX 10
B 3254 A22 0 8 DD BIX 15
B 3254 A22 0 8 DD BIX 16
B 3254 A22 0 8 DD BIX 22
B 3254 A22 0 8 DD BIX 23
C 5554 L21 1 8 DD CDE 25
C 5554 L21 1 8 DD CDE 26
C 5554 L21 1 8 DD CDE 32
C 5554 L21 1 8 DD CDE 35
C 5554 L21 1 8 DD CDE 37
```

file2

```
A 97276 X700 MULTI.NOD 22:22 790 2097152 op 3 true 0 prev1 _xx fix
B 3254 A22 MULTI.NOD 11:14 15 1572864000 op 1 true 0 prev1 _xx fix
B 3254 A22 MULTI.NOD 11:15 16 524288640 op 1 true 0 prev1 _xx fix
B 3254 A22 MULTI.NOD 11:16 17 1572864000 op 1 true 0 prev1 _xx fix
C 5554 L21 MULTI.NOD 00:16 00 1572864000 op 1 true 0 prev2 _xx fix
```

output should be:

```
A 97276 X700 MULTI.NOD 22:22 790 2097152 op 3 true 0 prev1 _xx fix A 97276 X700 0 6 DD V8 2006
B 3254 A22 MULTI.NOD 11:14 15 1572864000 op 1 true 0 prev1 _xx fix B 3254 A22 0 8 DD BIX 06
B 3254 A22 MULTI.NOD 11:15 16 524288640 op 1 true 0 prev1 _xx fix B 3254 A22 0 8 DD BIX 07
B 3254 A22 MULTI.NOD 11:16 17 1572864000 op 1 true 0 prev1 _xx fix B 3254 A22 0 8 DD BIX 08
C 5554 L21 MULTI.NOD 00:16 00 1572864000 op 1 true 0 prev2 _xx fix C 5554 L21 1 8 DD CDE 25
```

eg. if file2 will be later as below

```
A 97276 X700 MULTI.NOD 17:4 790 2097152 op 3 true 0 prev1 _xx fix
A 97276 X700 MULTI.NOD 18:4 790 2097152 op 3 true 0 prev1 _xx fix
A 97276 X700 MULTI.NOD 19:4 790 2097152 op 3 true 0 prev1 _xx fix
A 97276 X700 MULTI.NOD 20:4 790 2097152 op 3 true 0 prev1 _xx fix
B 3254 A22 MULTI.NOD 11:11 15 1572864000 op 1 true 0 prev1 _xx fix
C 5554 L21 MULTI.NOD 00:16 00 1572864000 op 1 true 0 prev2 _xx fix
C 5554 L21 MULTI.NOD 00:44 00 1572864000 op 1 true 0 prev2 _xx fix
C 5554 L21 MULTI.NOD 00:88 00 1572864000 op 1 true 0 prev2 _xx fix
```

output then will be then:

```
A 97276 X700 MULTI.NOD 17:4 790 2097152 op 3 true 0 prev1 _xx fix A 97276 X700 0 6 DD V8 2006
A 97276 X700 MULTI.NOD 18:4 790 2097152 op 3 true 0 prev1 _xx fix A 97276 X700 0 6 DD V8 2007
A 97276 X700 MULTI.NOD 19:4 790 2097152 op 3 true 0 prev1 _xx fix A 97276 X700 0 6 DD V8 2008
A 97276 X700 MULTI.NOD 20:4 790 2097152 op 3 true 0 prev1 _xx fix A 97276 X700 0 6 DD V8 2009
B 3254 A22 MULTI.NOD 11:11 15 1572864000 op 1 true 0 prev1 _xx fix B 3254 A22 0 8 DD BIX 06
C 5554 L21 MULTI.NOD 00:16 00 1572864000 op 1 true 0 prev2 _xx fix C 5554 L21 1 8 DD CDE 25
C 5554 L21 MULTI.NOD 00:44 00 1572864000 op 1 true 0 prev2 _xx fix C 5554 L21 1 8 DD CDE 26
C 5554 L21 MULTI.NOD 00:88 00 1572864000 op 1 true 0 prev2 _xx fix C 5554 L21 1 8 DD CDE 32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
    FNR == 1 { delete count }
    { key = $1 SUBSEP $2 SUBSEP $3; count[key]++ }
    FNR == NR { file1[key, count[key]] = $4 OFS $5 OFS $6 OFS $7 OFS $8; next }
    { print $0, file1[key, count[key]] }
' file1 file2
```

The key here is to keep a count of how many times the key has been seen, so you can match the data from file1 with the nth key from file2.

---

This is a little more code, but it's more flexible regarding the layout of file1

```
awk '
    FNR == 1 { delete count }
    { key = $1 SUBSEP $2 SUBSEP $3; count[key]++ }
    FNR == NR {
        data = ""
        for (i = 4; i <= NF; i++)
            data = data OFS $i
        file1[key, count[key]] = data
        next
    }
    { printf "%s%s%s", $0, file1[key, count[key]], ORS }
' file1 file2
```